# Cannot connect SSH through PuttY even though server is online

Tags: ssh, vpn, putty, port

I'm trying to connect to a server via SSH. The server is reachable according to http://www.infobyip.com/sshservertest.php and SSH works without problems on Android (JuiceSSH). 
However, PuttY errors out with the message **"Network error: connection timed out".**

Since the server is connected to a VPN I enabled port forwarding on the VPN server from the public port XXXXX to the local port 22. Could there be any issue in PuttY with the 5 digit port used for SSH?

The connection directly to the server worked well before setting up the VPN.

Comment: PuTTY should not have problems with 5 digit port number. Can you connect with any other SSH client from the same machine?

Comment: Sorry, should have checked this before - I also can't connect through WinSCP. I'll check if there are certain connections being blocked, never had a problem before without using the VPN.